# Core Data migration after removing entity from scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

For this example lets say my Core Data model is this:

```
Person
------  
- firstName  (string)
- lastName (string)  

- address (to-one relationship with Address)  

Address  
-------  
- streetName  (string)
- streetNumber (int)  

- person (to-one relationship with Person)
```

Now for the next version of my app, I would like to simplify my model to be:

```
Person
------  
- firstName  (string)
- lastName (string)  
- address (string)
```

As you can see I removed the `Address` entity from my model scheme and added a "address" string property in `Person` instead of the to-one relationship with `Address` entity.

My question is how do do this kind of migration?

Of course I need to adjust my model for the new structure so what I'm thinking to do is to go over all my `Person` object and do something like:

```
for (Person *per in allPersons) {    
   NSString *stName = per.address.streetName;  
   NSString *stNum = per.address.streetNumber;
   per.address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", stName, stNum];
}
```

Problem is the address entity is no longer exist in my new scheme, so how can I do `per.address` ?

I suppose I need to use the migration manager or mapping model, just not sure how it will help me, and how to use it.
I'll appreciate a simple example for this kind of use case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the migration options that are available in Core Data, but in this scenario it will not be sufficient to use the so-called `Lightweight migration`. The learning curve for custom migration is considerable.

Another option is to simply leave the `Address` entity in the model so you can use it for the "manual" migration process. When the app starts up the first time with the new scheme, use this entity to construct the new address string.

In the rest of your code you simply ignore it. This seems to me to be the most practical  and simplest solution.

Comment: can you give an example of how you do such a migration? or reference to an example

Comment: Nothing for you to do. Just use [lightweight migration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html) to change the names of the attributes and add new ones (follow the link), then on first run copy them over in a loop.

Comment: i was talking about the custom migration option, of i need mapping model for this?